# Specification pattern - creating compound specifications using lambdas (C#)

Tags: c#, lambda, specification-pattern

If I have a specification defined as an Expression as below:

```
public Expression<Func<Foo, bool>> IsSuperhuman = 
  x => x.CanFly && x.HasXRayVision;
```

And I want to define another specification 'IsSuperheroine' with the logic 'is superhuman and is female', how can I reuse the existing specification within the new one?

Comment: Why are you using Expressions for this? It would seem a delegate would suffice.

Comment: Because you can't use simple delegates in the Where clause of IQueryables, as I discovered yesterday.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Have you checked out [predicate builder](http://www.albahari.com/nutshell/predicatebuilder.aspx) in LinqKit? It builds up expressions by letting you and and or expressions together.

Comment: I believe that NCommon has something similar but I'm down with rolling my own at the moment.

Comment: I'm an absolute spanner. If I'd read your link properly, it could have saved me loads of work. You are a god!

Answer (score 1):

Here's a way to do it :

```
Expression<Func<Foo, bool>> IsSuperhuman = x => x.CanFly && x.HasXRayVision;

Expression<Func<Foo, bool>> IsSuperheroine = AndAlso(IsSuperhuman, x => x.IsFemale);

...

public static Expression<Func<T, TResult>> AndAlso<T, TResult>(Expression<Func<T, TResult>> expr1, Expression<Func<T, TResult>> expr2)
{
    var arg = Expression.Parameter(typeof(T), expr1.Parameters[0].Name);
    var andExpr = Expression.AndAlso(
        ReplaceParameter(expr1.Body, expr1.Parameters[0], arg),
        ReplaceParameter(expr2.Body, expr2.Parameters[0], arg));
    return Expression.Lambda<Func<T, TResult>>(andExpr, arg);
}

public static Expression ReplaceParameter(Expression expr, ParameterExpression oldParam, ParameterExpression newParam)
{
    return new ReplaceParameterVisitor(oldParam, newParam).Visit(expr);
}

internal class ReplaceParameterVisitor : ExpressionVisitor
{
    private ParameterExpression _oldParam;
    private ParameterExpression _newParam;

    public ReplaceParameterVisitor(ParameterExpression oldParam, ParameterExpression newParam)
    {
        _oldParam = oldParam;
        _newParam = newParam;
    }

    protected override Expression VisitParameter(ParameterExpression node)
    {
        if (node == _oldParam)
            return _newParam;
        return node;
    }
}
```

It is probably not the simplest way to do it, but it works...

Comment: Thanks! I'm going to take your word for it until such a time as I've been through the Expressions API and worked out what it all means.